# In C++, is there a difference in memory usage between "enum class" versus "enum"?

Tags: c++11, enums

I understand the benefits of using the strongly typed "enum class" over "enum", but a classmate and I are wondering if one or the other takes up more memory.

Comment: I do not see a reason for enum class to use more memory (unless you specified the large base type). Why not create a simple program and experiment?

Comment: I'd imagine most of the differences would be handled during compilation, not at runtime (no change in memory). This should be pretty easy to test, though - just make two (almost) identical programs, compile, and compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum class`s are still just integral values with no additional overhead. However an `enum class`'s underlying type defaults to `int` while regular `enum` the type is unspecified and the implementation is free to select a minimal integral type. So in theory if you don't specify the underlying type an `enum class` may be bigger than a plain `enum`.

## C++ specification 7.2.5 - Enumeration Deceleration

`enum class`

> The underlying type can be explicitly specified using enum-base; if not explicitly specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is `int`.

`enum`

> If no initializer is specified for the first enumerator, the initializing value has an unspecified integral
> type.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent, well-documented, and easy to understand answer!

Comment: It's also an excellent lesson to learn that if memory constraints are a concern, I can specify the data type to use. For example: enum class Color : char {Red, White, Blue};