# What should the underlying type of a char initialized enum be?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

When answering this [question about enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336578/in-c-is-there-a-difference-in-memory-usage-between-enum-class-versus-enum/38336740#38336740) I read the spec regarding the underlying size and it says (regarding unscoped enums) [7.5.5]:

> If the underlying type is not fixed, the type of each enumerator is the type
>   of its initializing value

But when I try the [following code](http://ideone.com/KgshjL) I get `sizeof int` for all enums (tested on g++, VC and clang).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum e1 { e1a };
enum class ec1 { ec1a };
enum e2 { e2a = 'a' }; // I expect this to have sizeof 1
enum class ec2 { ec2a = 'a' };

int main() {
    cout << "plain enum:" << sizeof(e1a) << endl;
    cout << "enum class:" << sizeof(ec1::ec1a) << endl;
    cout << "char initialized plain enum:" << sizeof(e2a) << endl;
    cout << "char initialized enum class:" << sizeof(ec2::ec2a) << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

> plain enum: 4
>   enum class:4
>   char initialized plain enum: 4
>   char initialized enum class: 4

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed this sentence:

> Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration.

Proof:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum e1 { e1a };
enum class ec1 { ec1a };
enum e2 {
    e2a = 'a' ,
    e2b = sizeof(e2a)  // <-- here the type of e2a is still char
};
// <-- here the type of e2a becomes the same as the type of e2 (i.e. int)

enum class ec2 { ec2a = 'a' };

int main() {
    cout << "plain enum:" << sizeof(e1a) << endl;
    cout << "enum class:" << sizeof(ec1::ec1a) << endl;
    cout << "char initialized plain enum:" << sizeof(e2a) << " but e2b=" << e2b <<endl;
    cout << "char initialized enum class:" << sizeof(ec2::ec2a) << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
plain enum:4
enum class:4
char initialized plain enum:4 but e2b=1
char initialized enum class:4
```